# JSF Validation error is not displaying before close Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a Jquery dialog to get user input.

```
<div id="icPopup">
    <td>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectICType" value="#{sessionBean.icStartLetter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select IC type"  style="width:100px;">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="- Select -"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{sessionBean.icStartLetterTypes}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </td>
    <td  align="center">
        <h:inputText id="icNumber" value="#{sessionBean.icNumber}"></h:inputText>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="mainBtnGrey" class="mainBtnLeftAlign">
            <h:commandLink action="#{home.checkICForError}" value="Confirm"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</div>
```

And my script code is

```
$('#mainBtnGrey').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#icPopup').dialog('close');
});
```

The issue here is, before display the validation errors the dialog is closed. How to keep open the dialog if the bean return the validation errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script code is present on the XHTML page within `<script/>`, you could just check the validation status of the EL using:

```
$('#mainBtnGrey').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  if(!#{facesContext.validationFailed})
    $('#icPopup').dialog('close');
});
```

`facesContext.validationFailed` will check the validation status of the entire JSF request for failure.

Comment: Hi, this one working fine. thanks. But one question. how this java script function is waiting until the facesContext return it validation status? I mean when button click we have to wait until server side validation return the value. how this waiting happen?