# JSF Validation error not printed in open dialog

Tags: jsf-2

I have to validate that a field in a form is not empty.

The problem is that the `form` is in a `JQueryUI dialog` (since I don't know how to create "windows" in JSF), so when I click the `commandButton` the page **is refreshed** and the JQuery dialog is lost. After refreshing, I can see the error message was printed in the page code by looking at the source code. If I use `ajax` in the `commandButton` then the page is not refreshed but I don't get the message printed, I got it as a sort of "Javascript alert" in the browser.

How can I get the error message without refreshing the page?

```
<h:inputText value="#{myController.name}" id="myname" required="true" requiredMessage="Name required">
    <f:ajax />
</h:inputText>
<h:message errorClass="..." for="myname" />
```

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224338/jsf-validation-error-is-not-displaying-before-close-jquery-dialog) looked similar to my problem but I don't think the solution is what I'm looking for.

Note: I am not using additional libraries like Primefaces, etc

Comment: It depends on how you are going to render the content of the jquery-Dialog. Your `<f:ajax>` needs to update that content after it's submitted, i.e. `<f:ajax render="IdOfTheContentWithinTheDialog">` http://ralph.soika.com/how-to-use-a-jquery-dialog-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. There is something missing there so I will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of the comment, I was able to solve it this way:

- In the `commandButton`, use `ajax` with both `render` and `execute` (`render` only **doesn't work**):

  ```
                      <h:commandButton id="...." action="#{myController.doSomething()}" type="submit" value="Do something">
                          <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                      </h:commandButton>
  ```
- Create a "pageUpdate()" method in `myController` that is called at the end of `myController.doSomething()`. This way, after the actions, the page is refreshed and the dialog is gone. There are of course other ways to close the dialog, but it is convenient for me to update the page when there is no error in the dialog action, so my objects in memory are updated too.

I think JQuery dialog messes with my styles after the ajax call returns with error, so check that out if you do it.